# Can't use double in TSQL CREATE PROC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a Syntax Error around that `double` , is there something wrong ? Is that safe to switch to `float` , but works ?

```
create proc S_average
(
    @dept_id char(10),
    @dept_name char(10) OUTPUT,
    @dept_avg double OUTPUT
)
AS
select @dept_name = name , @dept_avg = payroll
from dbo.employees
where id = @dept_id;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `double` datatype in SQL Server.  You should be using `float` in place of that (or `real` in earlier versions, but you don't have a SQL Server version posted).

`float` doesn't have quite the same precision as `double` in C# (again, I'm assuming a .NET language as it isn't posted) if you are looking to pass values to the application.  But `float` is the closest to C#'s `double` and almost definitely going to be perfect for your requirement.

Comment: @warl0ck ok, perfect.  Use `float` then.  That will work for you.